# how to build docker image using jenkins x

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, dockerhub, jenkins-x

I am trying to build docker Image using jenkins x and I have created kubernetes cluster using minikube. got an error `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/sarika-ps_go-k8s_master@tmp/durable-6564436e/script.sh: docker: not found`. I have installed the docker plugin on jenkins x. Please help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what kind of project are you trying to build? If you try to [import](https://jenkins-x.io/developing/import/) your code you'll hopefully find your project gets setup correctly.

basically Jenkins X uses build pods to run the pipelines which already have all the software tools required for pipelines (docker, skaffold, kubectl etc) inside the build pod which is defined as a docker image.

Try to reuse one of the existing build pods - e.g. using `jenkins-maven` as the build agent:

```
 pipeline {
  agent {
    label "jenkins-maven"
  }
  stages {
    stage('release') {
      steps {
        container('maven') {
          sh "docker build -t foo:bar ."
...
```

or you could try [create a custom build pod](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/create-custom-builder/).

Comment: I am trying to build a simple Docker image but its showing docker not found while executing build command